# Source: God only gives people what they can handle

Tags: sources-mekorot, suffering

I have heard it quoted many times in a variety of contexts the following words: "Hashem only gives people what they can handle" or "Hashem never gives people more than they can handle."

I assumed the source of this statement was the Gemarah "Ayn HKB"H ba b'trunyah im briyosav", however, this Gemarah is referring to a different point: God does not demand from a person more than they can do. The idea I am quoting is that God does not give anyone a challenge they cannot overcome, not that God doesn't expect one to overcome an overwhelming challenge.

I'm looking for a source that confirms or denies the statement as I heard it.

Comment: I hope my question is clear - feel free to edit it for clarity. I'm looking for sources proving or disproving a comment people say.

Comment: @Rish Strongly related, thanks. But not duplicate - I'm asking about this specific wording, which those answers don't directly address.

Comment: `what God demands of a person vs. what circumstances He gives to a person.` It depends what you mean by "handle"; God sometimes puts people in situations where they cannot survive, for example. So a person can't be expected to "handle" (i.e. survive) a 10-ton boulder crashing down on them (though they should never despair that God *might* allow them to survive through divine mercy). But if by handle, you mean "respond to appropriately," then it does seem that this is essentially a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: @Fred Here are some synonyms: "handle" means "cope with" "manage" "be ok despite" "hold things together". Someone who has a mental breakdown, is not "handling it" according to the (faulty?) quote above. Again, please make any edits you think would enhance clarity.

Comment: @LN6595 So are you asking (for example) whether everyone who ever had a mental breakdown could have avoided it if they had only used their capabilities in the given circumstances in the best way they could?

Comment: @Fred That would be the implication of the quote. Is it correct? Is it a Jewish idea at all?

Comment: Re "what God demands of a person vs. what circumstances He gives to a person", it's unclear to me which of those you're asking about and which you're attributing to that source.

Comment: @msh210 I edited the question and hopefully clarified it. I know this was marked as a duplicate but I am specifically *not* looking for a discussion of the Gemarah quoted in the other question.

Comment: (re your last comment) The other question doesn't mention _g'mara_, and seems exactly the same to me as this one.

Comment: @msh210 Yes, but the answers to the question do. The difference between my question and that question are admittedly quite subtle.